# Why two lists with different names and same types that are outputs of a SQL query, have effect on each other C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, entity-framework-core, tracking

I have a DB table with name of Color.

```
public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public bool MaterialStatus { get; set; }
    public bool GoodsStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I defined two lists of color that have same or different records.

```
List<Color> colors1 = _context.Colors.Where(c => c.MaterialStatus == true).ToList();
List<Color> colors2 = _context.Colors.Where(c => c.GoodsStatus == true).ToList();
```

For example output is:

> colors1 ={(1,bl,blue,true,true) , (2,gr,green,true,true) , (3,bk,black,true,false)}
> colors2 ={(1,bl,blue,true,true) , (2,gr,green,true,true) , (3,wt,white,false,true)}

then I did some changes on these list like below:

```
colors1.ForEach(c => c.ColorCode = c.ColorCode + " || " + c.ColorName);
ViewBag.Colors1 = new SelectList(colors1, "Id", "ColorCode");

colors2.ForEach(c => c.ColorCode = c.ColorCode + " || " + c.ColorName);
ViewBag.Colors2 = new SelectList(colors2, "Id", "ColorCode");
```

desired output must be:

> ViewBag.Colors1.Items = {(1,"bl || blue"),(2,"gr || green"),(3,"bk || black")}

> ViewBag.Colors2.Items = {(1,"bl || blue"),(2,"gr || green"),(3,"wt || white")}

problem is there. changing on colors2 have effects on colors1 and output will be wrong, like below:

> ViewBag.Colors1.Items = {(1,"bl || blue || blue"),(2,"gr || green || green"),(3,"bk || black")}

> ViewBag.Colors1.Items = {(1,"bl || blue || blue"),(2,"gr || green || green"),(3,"wt || white")}

I don't realize why this happened. How can I prevent this problem and get correct output?

### **correct answer:**

I changed my code by adding `AsNoTracking()` at the end of query, and it worked!!!!

```
List<Color> colors1 = _context.Colors.Where(c => c.MaterialStatus == true).AsNoTracking().ToList();
List<Color> colors2 = _context.Colors.Where(c => c.GoodsStatus == true).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: You are manipulating the actual db entities. Don't. Project to a type that you create specifically for the purpose of displaying. The entities are being cached. That's why you get the same instances from both queries (where they overlap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're fetching those from an ORM (EF, etc): note that ORMs tend to use (by default) an identity cache, so that if they see the same logical row (same table and primary key) twice in the same data-context, they give you the same object instance each time. This is for consistency.

Ultimately, you shouldn't change tracked ORM entities unless you intend to a: see that change reflected everywhere, and b: commit that change to the database. If you want something transient: *project the entity into your own non-tracked type*.